# Can I make a node group driver independent of materials?

Tags: node-editor, drivers, properties

I made a node group that contains a color ramp, and in order to control the color ramp from the outside I read that I have to use drivers. I have never used drivers before and feel lost right now.

[image]

So I copied the data paths from my color ramp sliders into the color ramp. The problem is that in the driver editor, I need to assign a material.

[image: Driver Editor]

But I want to be able to use the node group in different materials.

[image]

The last picture shows two objects with different materials. The material of Suzanne is assigned in the driver editor and works the way I want. But when I change the sliders of Suzanne, I also affect the purple sphere; if I'm in the sphere's material, the sliders do nothing.

Is there a way to make the drivers work without assigning a material? Or can I make a variable that always links to the current material?

Comment: An alternative solution: [Build color ramp out of math nodes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/40120/78972) :)

Comment: Probably by using a scripted expression that references the current material, rather than using a variable.