# control colorramp by a driver by a shading value

Tags: drivers, shader-nodes

[image]

I want to control the "pos" value of the color ramp (here the 0.5) by a driver.
This would be easy, but...
the driver should be controlled by a value from the same shader nodes tree.

Is this possible? Or some clever workaround?

so e.g. i want to change the pos value by the y value here:

[image]

This is just an example - i need the driver. ;)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['color' and 'position' input for Color Ramp node?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/248092/color-and-position-input-for-color-ramp-node) Here I explained how you can either use drivers or - in your case probably better - simulate the _Color Ramp_ with a _Map Range_ node to mix colors. You can plug the Y value into the _From Max_ input. But look at the other answer there, too. There is a more complex setup for building a color ramp with more sliders.

Comment: Ah sorry, my fault - your color ramp is set to constant. In this case you can use a simple _Mix Color_ shader and for the mix factor you plug the Y value into a _Math_ node set to _Greater Than_ with the slider position as _Threshold_. But when you say this is just an example it may be important what exactly you need the driver for - different ways to use it might need different kinds of solutions. The more I think about it the less I understand how this actually should work - let's say the Y value varies along the geometry, then you want the slider position to vary as well?

Comment: for two values your solution proposal would be no problem, but if you have several stops and you want to control them, it would be soon become a pretty messy shader nodes setup with lots of mix nodes. I hoped i could output and input a value via shader nodes (or somehow else). That's why i wanted to use a driver driven by a shader value.

Comment: ...that's why I said the solution might depend on what you **actually** want and not only the example. Also when you say several - for example, if several means 3 or 4 I would say, maybe a bit messy but better than nothing if you don't have any other solution. If we talk about 10 to 20 stops... well, that's gonna be really messy ;)

Comment: that's why i wrote: it's just an example, i need the driver ;)

Comment: Yeah, I see... the problem is you won't get that as driver, which would be the most simple solution. Since you can't get a driver, we need a workaround - and for the workaround it is helpful to know in which way the example differs from the real use. So in this case it is more or less you want to position many sliders instead of just one, is this correct? Or do you need them somewhere else as well, not only for the sliders?

Comment: Also the source for the drivers might get important: _Object_ texture coordinates are dependent on location, rotation and scale of the object so you could get the Y values somewhere and maybe use them as driver. But if you use them only in the example and the real values come from a different source it might be more complicated.

Comment: yep, just many sliders, and yes, the y object value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142754/discussion-between-gordon-brinkmann-and-chris).